# Controlling chromedriver port usage in a Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am currently running Chrome tests using Selenium Grid and am using the default 4444 and 5555 ports to comunicate between the hub and nodes. 
Everything is running fine but I do see that on the selenium nodes multiple chromedrivers are started and each listens on a seemingly random (albeit available) port number.

I see this using the command

```
netstat -tulpn | grep chromedriver
```

which returns for example

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18955         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51665/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17932         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51365/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34668         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51206/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43629         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51219/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5645          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10353/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48782         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51221/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26258         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51271/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19699         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51308/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36787         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51207/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28180         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51663/chromedriver
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29076         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51295/chromedriver
```

Normally this is ok, but occasionally they use a port in the 9500->9599 range which is used by Xvnc, causing errors when starting and stopping vncservers.

Is there a way to force chromedriver to use or avoid a specific range of ports? Existing answers using ChromeDriverService seem only to address the chromedriver port issue when running locally, and set the port to a single specific value.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any experience with grid, but there should be a way with chromedriver, pass an arguments to use certain ports. My bad, if the below command doesn't work.

--testing-fixed-https-port

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#testing-fixed-https-port